# Node server Multer req.files is empty

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, multer, alamofireimage

I've been trying to upload several images to my Node js server via the multer array method, and I've read and tried about 20 different ways with no luck. I'm uploading via iOS using the Alamofire .upload method, which generates a multipart/form-data for the http body. I am able to successfully upload a single image, but not an array.

### iOS portion

```
Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            for img in images {
                guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.25) else { 
                    return 
                }
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "photo")
            }
    },
```

### route.js

```
var upload = multer({
    dest: './jobs',
    limits: (40 * 1024 * 1024), // (MB * kb * bytes)
    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
});

router.post("/xyz/:id/upload", upload.array('photo'), function (req, res) { //  upload.single('photo')
    console.log("POST to job photo upload route \n");
    const mDy = new Date().toLocaleDateString(format, dateOptions);
    var filePath = String("xyz/" + req.params.id + " " + mDy + ".jpg");
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

    req.pipe(writeStream);
    console.log(req.files);

    req.on('end', () => {
        res.send(201, "photos saved");
        console.log("photos saved");
    });

});
```

Comment: So using upload.array('photo'), I am able to get data in the req.body but it doesn't appear to be in array form.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to solve this, had been missing the

```
fileName: "photo.jpg"
```

attribute in this line:

```
multipartFormData.append(imageData, fileName: "photo.jpg", withName: "photo")
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped almost 2 years later